# How to filter rows with column constraint in Deequ ColumnProfileRunner?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-deequ

I am new to Scala and Spark. I am exploring the Amazon Deequ library for data profiling.

How do I get count of rows having a particular value while using ColumnProfilerRunner()?

The AnalysisRunner has an option of "compliance" I am looking for a similar option to filter rows that comply with the given column constraint.

I have multiple columns hence I want to check dynamically instead of using column names.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deequ's column profiler computes a fixed set of statistics. If you want to compute custom statistics of your data, you should use the VerificationSuite. Checkout the examples on deequ's github page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. The VerificationSuite examples uses a column name as an argument for custom constraints. Can you please point out how do I use it for all columns dynamically without using column name as argument? My data set has dynamic columns and I am trying to  filter rows of all columns having a particular value .

Comment: You can use the DataFrame API to retrieve all the column names and then dynamically build the checks for the VerificationSuite